# IntelliJ command line compiler

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea, compiler-warnings, headless

I'm searching for an automated way to collect all the IntelliJ static code analysis warnings (compiler and inspections) without having to run a UI and click on buttons. Ideally I'd like run the IntelliJ compiler from the command line and have it log all warnings into a file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [Working with IntelliJ IDEA Features from Command Line](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html):

> To launch a code inspection from the command line, specify the
>   following command line arguments:
>
> 1. Path to the launcher: specify the full path to one of the following launchers (which reside under the bin directory of your
>      IntelliJ IDEA installation):
>
>    - For Windows: `inspect.bat`
>    - For UNIX : `inspect.sh`
> 2. Project file path is the full path to the *.ipr file or .idea directory of the project to be inspected.
> 3. Inspection profile path is the full path to the profile, against which the project should be inspected. The inspection profiles are
>      stored under `USER_HOME\.IntelliJ IDEAXX\config\inspection`
> 4. Output path is the full path to an existing directory where the report will be stored.
> 5. Options. You can specify: The directory to be inspected -d  The verbosity level of output -vX, where X
>      is 0 for quiet, 1 for noisy and 2 for extra noisy.
>
> Please note that you have to specify full paths, relative paths are
>   not accepted.